# How do I run burrows-wheeler aligner on windows subsystem for linux?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, burrows-wheeler-transform

Total newbie here and have no idea on what I'm doing.
I have installed ubuntu on windows can open bash from windows now.

I have also downloaded burrow-wheeler aligner from the Sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/bio-bwa/files/

From there I tried extracting the bz2 file. And I added the extracted folder into PATH

but when I type in bwa on bash, it says bwa: command not found

I'm a total beginner and want to get started with bioinformatics. I performed the aforementioned steps because that's how I setup conda to work on windows cmd.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the command `ls -l $(realpath ` _ThePathTobwa_ `)` show?

Comment: If you have conda installed, a good option would be to add the bioconda channel (http://www.ddocent.com//bioconda/) and install it using `conda install bwa`. If you need help installing/using bioinformatics software, https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ is a better community to engage with

Comment: @jared_mamrot  I have Conda installed for windows not for Linux. So I can't use conda install bwa on bash

Comment: Btw, I just tried building the `bwa` version you pointed out. It fails linking - so there is no `bwa` binary. If you instead download it from github (`git clone git@github.com:lh3/bwa.git; cd bwa; make`) it works.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it shows -bash: "the directory": Is a directory                            total 620                                                                                                                     lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      7 Feb 20 05:18 bin -> usr/bin                                          drwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4096 Feb 20 05:26 boot                                                              drwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4096 Apr 24 16:07 dev                                                          drwxr-xr-x  1 root root   4096 Apr 24 16:07 etc; And a lot more of these

Comment: If you tried following @TedLyngmo's instructions and encountered an error, consider installing conda on WSL, e.g. https://davetang.org/muse/2019/04/09/setting-up-windows-for-bioinformatics-in-2019/

Comment: I meant the full path to `bwa`, not the directory it is in. What was the exact error you encountered when trying to build the github version?

Answer (score 0):

In the subsystem, almost everything remains the same in your scenario just as an Ubuntu system, then you just follow the Readme file of this repository: [lh3/bwa](https://github.com/lh3/bwa). Since [the repo in Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bio-bwa/files/) seems to have been archived for a long time, you'd better use [the newer alternative on Github](https://github.com/lh3/bwa).